# Rails fetch image and display in my index view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I am trying to build a rails application in which I am uploading image using carrierwave .After uploading now i want to retrieve that image and display in my index page but i don't know how to specify the path of the image or how to retrieve that image and show it in view.Also i want to display the details like title and description which I have uploaded 

[uploads_controller.rb]

```
class UploadsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user! 

  def index
    @uploads=Upload.all
  end

  def new
    @upload=Upload.new
  end


  def create

    @upload=Upload.new(params_abc)

     if  @upload.save  
        redirect_to  @upload
     else
       render 'new'
     end

  end
def show
    @post = find_params
  end

private

  def params_abc
        params.require(:upload).permit(:title,:description,:tageline)
  end
  def find_params
      Post.find(params[:id])
    end

end
```

[uploads/new.html.erb]

```
<%= form_for @upload,html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
    <% if @upload.errors.any? %>
        <div id="errors">
            <h2><%= pluralize(@upload.errors.count, "error") %> prevented this post from saving:</h2>
            <ul>
                <% @upload.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                    <li><%= msg %></li>
                <% end %>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <% end %>

    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %><br>
    <br>

    <%= f.label :description %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :description %><br>
     <br>

    <%= f.label :tageline %><br>
    <%= f.file_field :tageline%><br>
    <br>

    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

[uploads/index.html.erb]

```
<% @uploads.each do |f| %>                      

<div id="page_wrapper">

        <div id="profile_image">
            <%= f.image "uploadss/post/"%>
        </div>

        <div id="content_link">
            <div id="content">
                <p>Being the richest man in the cemetery doesn't matter to me. Going to bed at night saying we've done something wonderful, that's what matters to me.
                </p>        
            </div>

            <div id="link">

                <button type="button" >Read More</button>
            </div>  
        <div>

</div>
    <br>
<% end %>
```

[migration]

```
class CreateUploads < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :uploads do |t|
        t.string :title, null: false
        t.string :description, null: false
        t.string :tageline, null: false
        t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

[upload.rb]

```
class Upload < ActiveRecord::Base

    validates :description,  presence: true
    validates :title,  presence: true
    validates :tageline, presence: true

    mount_uploader :tageline, TagelineUploader 


end
```

[uploader]

```
# encoding: utf-8

class TagelineUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  # include CarrierWave::RMagick
  # include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  storage :file
  # storage :fog

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    "uploadss/post/#{model.id}"  
  end

  # Provide a default URL as a default if there hasn't been a file uploaded:
  # def default_url
  #   # For Rails 3.1+ asset pipeline compatibility:
  #   # ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_'))
  #
  #   "/images/fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_')
  # end

  # Process files as they are uploaded:
  # process :scale => [200, 300]
  #
  # def scale(width, height)
  #   # do something
  # end

  # Create different versions of your uploaded files:
  # version :thumb do
  #   process :resize_to_fit => [50, 50]
  # end

  # Add a white list of extensions which are allowed to be uploaded.
  # For images you might use something like this:
  # def extension_white_list
  #   %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  # end

  # Override the filename of the uploaded files:
  # Avoid using model.id or version_name here, see uploader/store.rb for details.
  # def filename
  #   "something.jpg" if original_filename
  # end

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do something like this in your uploads/index.html.erb file:

```
 <%= image_tag(f.tageline.url) %>
```

int the same way you can display other fields:

```
 <%= f.title %>
 <%= f.description %>
```